# Connect to sql database using Active Diretory interactive in .Net core Web app

Tags: sql-server, azure, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to access Azure database using Active Directory Interactive.

I am able to access the database when project is running locally (in Visual Studio). When I click run query a new browser window, it is opening and I am able to run query. But when I publish the application to Azure App Service, it does not work.

I have added AAD adminstrator to SQL Server.

Requirement is: every user will have to login with Microsoft account to run query on database, all the users have been added to AAD group.

```
var connectionString = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive; Database=testdb";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{ 
    // Here an exception occurs when app is running on app service
    connection.Open();  
}
           
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    var data = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check that you followed all the below steps:

**1. [Provision an Azure AD administrator for your Azure SQL DB Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#provision-an-azure-active-directory-administrator-for-your-azure-sql-database-server)**

***Note:*** Please ensure that you set a user as the AAD administrator for your Azure SQL Server.

**2. Connect to your** ***Azure SQL DB*** with the ***AAD account*** in step1. You can use SSMS or just connect to your DB from the Azure Portal.

**3. Add service principal and assign a role**

```
CREATE USER [Azure_AD_principal_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'Azure_AD_principal_name';
```

**4. Code sample**

```
string sqlResource = "https://database.windows.net/";
string tenantId = "e4c9ab4e-****-****-****-230ba2a757fb";
string serverName = "{server}.database.windows.net";
string databaseName = "{database}";

var token = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync(sqlResource, tenantId).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

string sqlConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source=tcp:{0},1433;Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False", serverName, databaseName);


using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    connection.AccessToken = token;
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Distinct TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The managed identity name of your VM should be entered in place of `Azure_AD_principal_name`. The members of the security group will all be able to connect to your Azure SQL database if you add your managed identity service principal to it and use the group name `Azure_AD_principal_name`.

Please let me know if you get any issue!

Comment: Thank you. have added AAD Administrator. and have completed 2,3 steps

Comment: @TaimurKhan - Hope you are adding the conn string. If not,  To get the conn string, Go To Azure portal > storage Account >  Access Keys(left panel) > Show keys > Connection string

Comment: It works on local, but not when i publish it to app service

Comment: @TaimurKhan, Could you please provide the exception logs you're getting!

Comment: There is no any exception while running app in visual studio, but when i publish app i am loging exception, its says "access denied" , but local app running fine

Comment: my app is in .Net core MVC

Comment: @TaimurKhan, Thanks, will repro once again to get access denied and will back with the fix